# Javascript print a variable with multilines

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a variable named `test` and inside it I had html content like

```
var test = "<div class='testingbot'>
                <span>TITLE</span>
            <div>";
```

When I use the above it crashes the page, but if I do it all as one line it works

```
var test = "<div class='testingbot'><span>TITLE</span><div>";
```

How would I be able to print with line breaks?

Thanks

Comment: You could opt to use CoffeeScript, which just automatically lets you do this (among a million other awesome things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't do multi-line strings like that, you need to just concatenate them together.

```
var test = "<div class='testingbot'>" +
               "<span>TITLE</span>" +
           "<div>";
```

Comment: I've stuck `\n` at the end before the closing `"` to make my new lines